# Parsing JSON file to Java Object

Tags: java, json, parsing

Underneath is a JSON file where it used an OCR from a pdf file table containing data and gets the JSON below. I want the contents of "DATE", "SUM", "MULTIPLE" from this JSON and convert to JAVA so then I can be able to store it to database. I've heard Jackson or JSON validator would do the trick, but in this JSON format, how can I approach this? For instance, you'll see "content": "DATE", how can I convert "DATE" into JAVA object, and then later store to a DataBase?

```
{"metadata": [],
"pages": [
{
"margins": {
"top": -1,
"left": -1,
"bottom": -1,
"right": -1
},
"box": {
"l": 0,
"t": 0,
"w": 738,
"h": 952
},
"rotation": {
"degrees": "0",
"origin": {
"x": "369",
"y": "476"
},
"translation": {
"x": "0",
"y": "0"
}
},
"pageNumber": 1,
"elements": [
{
"id": 519,
"type": "paragraph",
"properties": {
"order": 0
},
"metadata": [],
"box": {
"l": 102.15,
"t": 118.92,
"w": 107.97,
"h": 106.68
},
"content": [
{
"id": 8,
"type": "line",
"properties": {
"order": 0,
"cr": 210.12,
"cl": 76.43
},
"metadata": [],
"box": {
"l": 168.78,
"t": 118.92,
"w": 41.35,
"h": 12.61
},
"content": [
{
"id": 7,
"type": "word",
"properties": {},
"metadata": [],
"box": {
"l": 168.78,
"t": 118.92,
"w": 41.35,
"h": 12.61
},
"content": "**DATE:**",
"font": 1
}
]
},
{
"id": 18,
"type": "line",
"properties": {
"order": 1,
"cr": 210.12,
"cl": 76.43
},
"metadata": [],
"box": {
"l": 102.15,
"t": 150.24,
"w": 104.5,
"h": 12.54
},
"content": [
{
"id": 16,
"type": "word",
"properties": {},
"metadata": [],
"box": {
"l": 102.15,
"t": 150.24,
"w": 46.49,
"h": 12.28
},
"content": "**SALES**",
"font": 1
},
{
"id": 17,
"type": "word",
"properties": {},
"metadata": [],
"box": {
"l": 152.34,
"t": 150.32,
"w": 54.31,
"h": 12.46
},
"content": "**ORDER:**",
"font": 1
}
]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you run into implementation issues?

Answer (score 0):

There are many JSON parsers for Java:

- [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md)

```
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    MyObject=gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyObject.class);
```

- [javax.json](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html)

```
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonString));
JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();
int myInt = jsonObject.getInt("myInt"); // or getString(), getJsonObject() etc.
```

- [JSON-Simple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple) (similar usage to `javax.json`)
- `org.json`: see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18998203/5798824)
- and many others to choose from...